# Disable days of the week in Kendo grid calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How would you go about disabling the selection of all days of the week except for Monday when editing a record of a Kendo grid that has a date field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot out-of-the-box. However you can try the following:

1. Create custom editor for the Grid like shown [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html).
2. Use datepicker which is configured with templates to display the next week like disabled. Similar way to the one shown [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datepicker/template.html).
3. Use the **change** event to prevent the user from selecting like demonstrated [here](http://jsbin.com/exapImi/2/edit).